# Sort numbers from smallest to biggest using vector instead of array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

So I am new to C++ and I am working on this problem that asks me to sort numbers with the insertion sort using vectors instead of arrays. I have worked sorting using the array and then I just made some minor changes in the code trying to solve the problem with vector. Here's what I've got now:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void fill_array(vector<int> v,int size, int& number_used);

void sort(vector<int> v, int number_used);

void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2);

int main()     
{
    cout << "This program sorts numbers from lowest to highest.\n";

    vector<int> sample;
    int number_used;

    fill_array(sample,10,number_used);
    sort(sample,number_used);

    cout << "In sorted order the numbers are:\n";
    for (int index =0; index < number_used; index++)
        cout << sample[index] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void fill_array(vector<int> v, int size, int& number_used)
{ 
         cout << "This program sorts numbers from lowest to highest.\n";
         cout << "Enter up to " << size << " nonnegative whole number.\n"
              << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";

         int index = 0,next; 
         cin >> next;
         while ((next >= 0) && (index < size))
         {
               v[index]=next;
               index++;
               cin >> next;
         }
         number_used = index;
}

void sort(vector<int> v, int number_used)
{
     int index;
     int index_backwards;

    for(index=0;index<number_used;index++)
    {
       for(index_backwards=index;index_backwards>0;index_backwards--)
       {
           if(v[index_backwards-1]>v[index_backwards])
           {
               swap_values(v[index_backwards-1], v[index_backwards]);
           }
       }
    }
}


void swap_values(int& v1, int& v2)
{
     int temp;
     temp = v1;
     v1=v2;
     v2=temp;
}
```

It went through the compile just fine. But when i run it, after i had input the numbers and hit enter, the program just stops running and shuts down. Is there anyone could help me fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to allocate space in your vector before you fill it.

Comment: Pass your vector parameters by reference, if you are manipulating them inside the functions: `void fill_array(vector<int>& v,int size, int& number_used);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `std::vector` like an array, you are misusing them. There is no point in passing the size "on a side" of the vector, because vectors keep their own size.

You should pass your vector by reference, use its `size()` member function instead of a `count()`, and use `push_back()` to add values to it. The signatures of your functions should be as follows:

```
// Pass by ref; no "size", no "number_used"
void fill_array(vector<int> &v);
// Pass by ref; no "number_used"
void sort(vector<int> &v);
```

Use `v.push_back(next)` instead of `v[index]=next` inside `fill_array` implementation.

Comment: The OP's fill_array() possibly needs a parameter for the size, to specify the number of values to insert into the vector.   The alternative is reading from cin until an error occurs (e.g. EOF) but the technique to trigger that is system dependent, and not always obvious to a user.

Comment: @Peter Since OP has mentioned that this code was originally for an array, I am reasonably certain that the `size` is there to say how big an array he's passing. This is also consistent with the way the `size` parameter is used as a "limiter" inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your `fill_array` function, you aren't adding the values that have been input to the vector v correctly. You should change `v[index] = next` to `v.push_back(next)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change

```
v[index]=next;
```

by

```
v.push_back(next);
```

Or you can keep it like v[index]=next; and allocate the memory when you declare your vector.

```
vector<int> sample(10);  // This allocates 10 element. DON'T use push_back in this case
```

When you go the push_back way and you know the number of element your vector will eventually have, it is a good thing to call reserve before starting filling the vector. So you want to do:

```
vector<int> sample;
sample.reserve(10);
...
// Now fill it with push_back
```

reserve will set the capacity or your vector (capacity is always >= to your vector size). When capacity is == to the size, a call to push_back (or any function that insert elements) will need to reallocate the memory and then you get some performance hit. Using reserve will prevent that.

Also, there is no point in having your own swap function. The standard library has already a swap function. Instead of

```
swap_values(v[index_backwards-1], v[index_backwards]);
```

You can do

```
std::swap(v[index_backwards-1], v[index_backwards]);
```